# Using another domain with Google App Engine

Tags: web-hosting, domains, google-workspace, google-app-engine

I'm trying to change my google app engine domain (domain.appspot.com) to the domain I bought from 1&1.com (mydomain.com). I went into the google app engine settings and added the domain. After making a Google Apps account, I was asked to verify my domain. The directions say that 1&1 doesn't allow me to create TXT records, so I can't use that method for verification. Their alternative is to upload an HTML file to my server, but I didn't buy hosting with my domain, I just bought the domain. My files are on domain.appspot.com. How can I make mydomain.com point to domain.appspot.com? I've added the ns1.googleghs.com as my nameservers in my 1&1 DNS settings, but I still can't verify my domain with Google Apps.

Answer (score 1):

1and1.com does allow you to set up your own MX records. If you set them up and enable the email without verifying the domain, it might work.

the mx servers for google are at http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174125

Might be worth a shot.

However, in future it would be a good idea to move to a registrar that allows you manage your dns without the need for hosting.